# Set a mapView zoom distance from setUserTrackingMode(.Follow, animated: true)

Tags: swift, mkmapview, swift2

I have my map view which currently follows the user location however, I want to set the amount it is zoomed in to show a 2km radius from the users location.

My question is how would you do this, is there a zoom function? Or do I need to work out distance from the location and set a corresponding coordinates/region.

How help is great as I'm extremely new to swift! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apple Swift Documentation from MKMapView](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/region)

> When you initialize a map view, you should specify the initial
>   **region** for that map to display. You do this by setting the region property of the map. A region is defined by a center point and a
>   horizontal and vertical distance, referred to as the span. The
>   **span** defines how much of the map at the given point should be visible and is also how you set the zoom level. Specifying a large
>   span results in the user seeing a wide geographical area and
>   corresponds to a low zoom level. Specifying a small span results in
>   the user seeing a more narrow geographical area and corresponds to a
>   higher zoom level.

So you have to set the **region** and the **span** value.

```
var span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.02, 0.02)
var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center:CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 
lat, longitude: long),span: span)
mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

I suggest you should follow the update of the didUpdateLocationFunction and set the fresh location value to the lat and long variable. The tracking mode not guarantee constant zoom level.

Comment: Amazing answer thank you, so to clear things up. I convert the userLocation into MKCoordinateRegion and then set the mapView to the region. And this should be done within didUpdateLocationFunction to keep the map constantly updated.

Comment: Also may I ask what the span value represent? what value meters or just a random number?

Comment: Of course. Span value represent latitudeDelta and longitudeDelta. LatitudeDelta represent: The amount of north-to-south distance (measured in degrees) to display on the map. LongitudeDelta: The amount of east-to-west distance (measured in degrees) to display for the map region. 1 span approximately 111 kilometers (69 miles) at the equator but shrinks to 0 kilometers at the poles. So you have to careful with the span.

Comment: I have it working perfectly! Thank you so much for a great response!